# Why is video playback in Safari much smoother than in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, video, safari

I have noticed an issue within the last 4 months that seems to be new. In short, videos play flawlessly in Safari, but not on Chrome or Firefox. CPU usage is 200%+ (on a 400% scale in Activity Monitor) while playing in Chrome or Firefox, but less than 50% on Safari for the same video. It's as if Safari has some kind of hardware acceleration that the others don't. But Safari is annoying because I can't take screenshots on non-YouTube websites. Is there a way to make Chrome play the same way as Safari?

EDIT: The answer is because the codec is different. Chrome streams "opus" by default instead of "mp4". By using the Chrome extension "h264ify" I was able to lower CPU usage while watching YouTube.

YouTube:

- Plays 1080p 60 FPS in Chrome but with 350% CPU usage. Codecs: av01.0.09M.08 (399) / opus (251)
- Plays in Safari with almost no CPU usage. But audio is distorted when playing at higher speed. CAN take screenshots or record. Codecs: avc1.64002a (299) / mp4a.40.2 (140)

A test 1080p 60 FPS video that makes my computer drop frames in Chrome:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o27W2ELMfho

Crunchyroll:

- Plays well in Safari. Cannot take screenshots or record.
- Drops frames in Chrome. Can take screenshots and record
- Drops less frames in Firefox

Hulu:

- Plays well in Safari. 1080p. Cannot take screenshots or record.
- Only 480p in Chrome and Firefox

Amazon Prime Video:

- Plays well in Safari
- Plays well in Chrome and Firefox, but drops frames if something else is running on my computer, e.g. another browser tab. Cannot take screenshots or record.
  Test video on Amazon Prime: The Boys Season 2 e7

Hardware:

- macOS 10.14.6
- MacBook Pro 2.5GHz mid-2012
- Intel Core i5
- 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB
- Safari 14.0 (no extensions)
- Google Chrome 86.0.4240.75 (Official Build) (x86_64) I tried disabling all extensions.

Comment: The basics as I know is is Safari is based on [WebKit](https://webkit.org) and Chrome, Firefox and Opera (for example) are all based on [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org). If video playback is smoother on your MacBook that would mean that the GPU (hardware acceleration) is being utilized for video playback in Safari and other browsers are — for some reason — not using the GPU. Now why am I not posting this as an answer? Easy: I don’t know the specifics. But in my case on a MacBook Air 2020 running macOS Catalina 10.15.7 I see no difference in speed for video playback.

Comment: I think the specifics are that Chrome and Firefox play a video that is encoded differently, at least in YouTube. Safari gets the MP4 and Chrome gets "opus" which I think is decoded in software. But now I want to know why that is and what I can do to fix it.